# How to hide the application bar in a Windows Phone 8.1 (WinJS) app?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I have a single AppBar declared in default.html for use throughout my application.

On some of the pages I need to show the App Bar and in some of the I need to hide the AppBar.

So far, my efforts to find the methods to hide and show the AppBar have met a dead end.

The documentation on MSDN says:

[AppBar.hide method : 
Hides the app bar on Windows and the secondary command menu on Windows Phone.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/br229668.aspx)

So, that method only hides the AppBar for Windows and not for a Windows Phone project.

I have also tried giving `display:none` as a CSS style, to no effect.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: I'm not sure about Winjs, but in C# you can surely hide the AppBar when you set `BottomAppBar = null`. Maybe you can try something similar.

Comment: Yes, I do know how to do this in C#. But my requirement is for WinJS. I'm totally stumped on how to do such a simple thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AppBar.Hide hides the secondary command bar on Windows Phone, not the main AppBar. If you want the entire AppBar to go away then this isn't the right property.

The easiest way is to declare the AppBar on pages that you want to show it and to leave it out on pages that you don't want it, but you should be able to hide it by disabling the AppBar on pages that you don't want it on.

I just modified the appbar-commands.js file in the [HTML AppBar control sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-bar-sample-a57eeae9) as follows and the appbar hides and shows as I click the hide and show buttons:

```
// These functions are used by the scenario to show and hide elements
function doShowItems() {
    document.getElementById('commandsAppBar').winControl.disabled = false;

    //document.getElementById('commandsAppBar').winControl.showCommands([cmdFavorite, cmdCamera]);
    document.getElementById('scenarioShowButtons').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('scenarioHideButtons').disabled = false;
}

function doHideItems() {
    document.getElementById('commandsAppBar').winControl.disabled = true;
    //document.getElementById('commandsAppBar').winControl.hideCommands([cmdFavorite, cmdCamera]);
    document.getElementById('scenarioHideButtons').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('scenarioShowButtons').disabled = false;
}
```

I also confirmed with the single-page navigation model navigating between two pages. If you aren't seeing the appbar hide and show when disabled and enabled then make sure you are calling the code to disable / enable the appbar. The PageControl's ready function may not be called when returning to a cached page.

Comment: `The PageControl's ready function may not be called when returning to a cached page` is there anything written on this topic? I am having troubles navigating back and forth through my stack and was looking for more info on internals of navigation?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to do it with C#, You can simply just type.. (If your appbar is called **ApplicationBar**)

```
ApplicationBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

This will instantly hide the AppBar! If you want your HTML Page to perform this action, it will be much complicated.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks but I wanted this for WinJS. AppBar control is a different one in WinJS and the above piece of code won't work for the WinJS control.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try below step in your code.

1. Add a event listener for appbar [beforeshow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212518.aspx)
2. In code of before show Check a condition with specific page name
   Like : if (WinJS.Navigation.location.match("test.html"))
3. According to you condition you can [Disable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700540.aspx) your appbar.

All the best..!!

Comment: Setting the AppBar `disabled` property to `true` seems to hide it, but setting it to `false` does not show it up again.

Comment: So once I set the AppBar `disabled` property, I can never enable it for any other page in the application.

Comment: One can toggle disable property. IF you derive page unload method just write disable = false.. and as per your need in ready function make true or false..